# Counting repeating numbers in an Array

Tags: c#, arrays

Fairly new to C#. Have an assignment for class that asks us to generate an array from user inputted values. This part is done and work's perfectly.

Now that the array is completed I need to be able to display each distinct number entered in the array in a Console.WriteLine, and how many times that number appeared and I'm a little lost on how to accomplish this.

Comment: rather than someone else doing your homework for you, do a little research and come back when you have a specific problem and you might just learn a little along the way.

Comment: Which .NET framework are you using? helps to figure if you can use Generics and/or LINQ or none.

Comment: this is more of a problem-solving question rather than a programming question IMO

Answer (score 6):

Are you allow to use LINQ? If so, investigate `GroupBy` and `Count()`. Basically there's a one-liner which will work here, but as it's homework I'll let you work out the details for yourself... ask for more help when you've had a go though, if you run into problems.

Comment: +1 for pointing to the start of the path, rather than the end

Answer (score 5):

You can create a dictionary in that the keys are numbers, and the values are counts of that specific number in the array, and then increase the values in the dictionary each time a number is found:

Example:

```
        int[] arrayOfNumbers = new int[] { 1, 4, 2, 7, 2, 6, 4, 4, };
        Dictionary<int, int> countOfItems = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        foreach (int eachNumber in arrayOfNumbers)
        {
            if (countOfItems.ContainsKey(eachNumber))
                countOfItems[eachNumber]++;
            else
                countOfItems[eachNumber] = 1;
        }
```

This code works in all C# versions, but if you are using C# 3 or greater you could use LINQ, as others are suggesting. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ Distinct() extension method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx

Comment: As for the time they appeared, you can use the Distinct()'s result to use Count() for each ocurrence.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (int item in array)
{
     Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
     int frequency = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
     {
         if (array[i] == item) ++frequency;
     }
     Console.WriteLine(frequency.ToString());
}
```

A dirty and brute force way. Considering your array is an "int" array. Otherwise, just change the types.

Comment: Note that this will print each number as many times as its count - so { 1, 1, 1 } would give "1 3;1 3; 1 3".

Comment: Good point. I'd use a dictionary solution to avoid such problems. Or a List<T> instead of an array w/ IndexOf() checking to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Without LINQ, you could keep track of the numbers you're generating. A data structure like a `Dictionary` could work well, mapping the numbers to how many times you've seen them so far.