# C# searching array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a random array and I must search how many times the integer number is in the array. This is what I have already. How would you search the resulting array?

```
Console.WriteLine("enter number:");

int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] array = new int[number];
Random rnd = new Random();

for ( int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = rnd.Next(0 , number);
}

foreach (int i in array)
{
    System.Console.Write(" {0}",i);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `array.Where(x => x == looing_for).Count` or something like that? If you want to count all numbers, `Dictionary`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919077/c-counting-repeating-numbers-in-an-array

Comment: Voted to close, as this question is primarily opinion-based.
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers rely on LINQ, here is the code to do so with plain C#

```
int count = 0;

foreach (int i in array)
{
    if (i == number)
        count = count + 1;
}
```

Note that in your existing code this will always produce `0` because the upper bound of `Random.Next()` is exclusive. You should change your code to something like this where the number entered is not linked to the array you generate:

```
int array_size = 1000;
int max_number = 100;
int[] array = new int[array_size];
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    array[i] = rnd.Next(0, max_number);

Console.WriteLine("enter number:");
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

foreach (int i in array)
    System.Console.Write("{0} ", i);

int count = 0;
foreach (int i in array)
    if (i == number)
        count = count + 1;

Console.WriteLine("Number {0} was found {1} times in the array", number, count);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(var g in array.GroupBy(x=>x))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Count:{1}",g.Key,g.Count())
}
```